# How to load resources which are bundled in an executable jar file which was generated by maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to load my resources which I have bundled in a jar file.
Originally they where placed under `src/main/resources/*.wav`.

To generate my jar file I have used the maven-jar-plugin.
If I unpack the jar file I can see the resource files.

In my source code I am loading the files with

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/my-file.wav"));
```

When I run the application via IntelliJ this seems to work.
However when I try to execute the generated jar file the resources cannot be loaded.

Did I miss something? Maybe the classpath?

**EDIT**
My pom.xml has the following build property:

```
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>MyMain</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>MyMain</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: *"If I unpack the jar file I can see the resource files"* Where in the jar file do you see them? If they are in the *root* of the jar file, it should have worked fine.

Comment: yes, they are in the root of the jar file

Comment: Please show your pom file....

Comment: Can you try to lookup the URL first and see what it looks like? `URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("/my-file.wav")`

Comment: It returns null :(

Comment: What command are you using to package the application? And to run it? ..can you double check that the jar containing the wav file is included in the classpath when you run the app from the cmd line?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.
The problem has not been with maven.

It was the source code, which should be changed to:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("my-resource.wav");
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url)
```